# Retrieve the Shared Preference value once it is cleared

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My question is that is it possible to retrieve the value of shared preference that was cleared from the activity. For example I have three activities. Some data is storing in activity A and it is retrieved in Activity B. In activity C, the shared preference value is cleared. Now what i want is that if the User gets back to activity B then again the shared preference value should be retrieved. Please Help as I am new to android development and i only have to use shared preference. **Is it possible?**

Comment: Not possible to clear and again get the value

Comment: You could use the `Bundle savedInstance` when swiping between activities, i.e. if you are on B, and then you change to C, before stopping that activity, you could save that value within the activity and then clear the value on shared preferences

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh editor.commit?

Comment: it is Not possible to clear sharedprefernce and again get the value of sharedprefernce but you provide default value of it like this
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("title",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String LanSettining = prefs.getString("language", null);

Comment: @horro Ok sir let me try this one

Comment: `editor.commit` to save change in preference data

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh it will get again the cleared value?

Comment: nopes , as i said `simply don't clear required data` or you can save it into sqlite db

Comment: store your data in local database like SQllite and when u needed retrive from it

Comment: Thank you everyone the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do following steps:

- Just before clearing shared preferences, retrieve the value of
     parameter (which you want to get in Activity B)from shared
     preference
- Save this in temporary variable
- Then, clear the share preferences
- After that, save the value in temporary variable to
     shared preferences and retrieve it in Activity B